# What is the propper way to polyfill datetime-local in react?

Tags: reactjs, datetime, datetimepicker, ecmascript-5

Firefox and Safari lacks the support of HTML5 input of type datetime-local,is there a way to use a polyfill so these inputs can be properrly used without the usage of a custom date time picker ?

the used input can be found [here](https://material-ui.com/demos/pickers/).